# SearchView not working when Languages are changed

Tags: android

I am using SearchView. Its completely working fine when I am using English language.

But in my application data is in Gujarati Language now When I try to use SearchView it not working .

How to do search like when user press A its display list of Gujarati item in which A come if we convert in English

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = newText.toString();

                if(adaptercategory!=null)
                {
                    adaptercategory.filter(text);
                }

                return false;
            }
```